# C# SqlCommand - Prevent typecasting if a string is specified as a parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, sqlcommand

I am using a SQL Server database in my C# project. Currently I give my SQL query parameters via the `AddWithValue` function without the explicit specification of inverted commas. Can I be sure that everything in this string is treated directly like a `varchar` in the database ?

Example:

```
String parameter = "12";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from A where b = @parameter");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameter", parameter);
```

Since I do not get any errors when I manually set quotes in the query

```
(... where b = '@parameter')
```

I assume that my parameter is not treated as `VARCHAR`?

From the official documentary, I am unfortunately not smart and the executed query is my information not easily visible.

Comment: IIRC, if you write `'@parameter'` one of two things will happen: a) You compare it to the value of `@parameter` with some extra quotation marks. b) You compare be to the string literal `'@parameter'`. Both will propably break string comparision. Those quotaion marks are the inferior way of anotating stirngs/varchars. Parameters are the proper, SQL injection proof method. I trust SQL paramters to deal with this: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Btw. if you want some extra runtime checks, you may want to use the variant where you specify the .NET type of the parameter. If you then somehow end up adding a Integer where a String was expected, you should be getting a Exception rather then a implicit conversion.

Comment: What happened when you examined the results of your queries?

Comment: Passing a string to AddWithValue will result in nvarchar rather than the desired varchar. In short, [avoid `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. So i will use AddWithValue, although it is more effort, since the sizes of the varchars must/should be specified manually. I also suspect that errors resulting from too small varchar sizes are unfortunately not obvious, but maybe im wrong.